# Can we By pass - These contacts have the same related account.Open the related account record and remove redundant account–contact relationships error

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, merge

We have enabled Many to Many relationships between Accounts and contacts using Account Contact relationship Junction Object.

When our users are trying to merge duplicate contacts we are getting the error "
These contacts have the same related account. Open the related account record and remove redundant account–contact relationships. Then try merging again."

The above error is out of the box from salesforce and this is expected as we are trying to merge contacts that are associated with more than one Account.

The workaround we are doing is going back to contact, remove the relationship and then continue to merge.

The question here can we have some automation in place to avoid the error and merge the contacts without going back and removing the relationship(Which is wasting time for the merge)

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks,
Vara

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution ?